# Is there away to wrap to the left an element that's positioned to the right using flexbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

So I have 2 elements on the same line where one is to the far left and the other the far right using `justify-content: space-between;`

For responsive purposes though I need to wrap the element on the right to the next line if it's about to overlap the element on the left.

I'm using `flex-wrap: wrap;` but when it wraps the "right" element is on a new line but it is still pushed to the right whereas I need it to be pushed to the left as otherwise there's just whitespace to it's left.

Comment: Post the code you use, so we can see how to help

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to select a wrapped flex child through a CSS rule. This would probably be better handled with a media query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why isn't `flex-wrap` working for you? Look at this simple example with `justify-content: space-between;` and where the right element wraps to the next line and they are both pushed to the left:

```css
.wrapper {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
 max-width: 500px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper div {
 display: block;
 width: 220px;
 height: 220px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess if OP's code would be like this there wouldn't be an issue, right? ... so if we wait until we get the actual code we would be able to answer properly ... and having a proper written question :)

Comment: You're right, it should have worked and it does now. Turns out the element was inheriting a `margin-left: auto` from somewhere else in the app. I just presumed it was the `justify-content` that was pushing it to the right. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. @LGSon I can see the future. Yea i know it's not proper SO guidelines. Downvote me. I still helped the OP that's what matters to me. Not the future of SO. Pretty sure they'll be fine

Comment: As it now turned out, there was nothing wrong with OP's code, hence this can now be closed as _a problem that can no longer be reproduced_